# How to extract data from an incomplete and duplicated json string?

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON string from a TCP/IP socket like this:

```
res = 'atus": "OK"}{"pos": {"q0": 1.00, "q1": -0.00}}{"status": "OK"}{"pos": {"q0": 2.00, "q1": -1.00}}{"status": "OK"}{"pos": {"q0": 3.00,'
```

It always contains at least one complete "pos" item, and I want to extract the values of the last "pos" item, as in the example

```
q0 = 2.00
q1 = -1.00
```

Is there a descent way to do it?

Comment: you mean `'"atus": "OK"}{"pos": {"q0": 1.00, "q1": -0.00}}{"status": "OK"}{"pos": {"q0": 2.00, "q1": -1.00}}{"status": "OK"}{"pos": {"q0": 3.00,"'` ?

Comment: @Epsi95 Sorry. It is corrected in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [`regular expression`](https://regex101.com/r/1nDiL1/1)

```py
import re

res = '"atus": "OK"}{"pos": {"q0": 1.00, "q1": -0.00}}{"status": "OK"}{"pos": {"q0": 2.00, "q1": -1.00}}{"status": "OK"}{"pos": {"q0": 3.00,"'


q0, q1 = [float(i) for i in re.findall(r'{"pos": {"q0": ([+-]?(?:[0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+), "q1": ([+-]?(?:[0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+)}}', res)[-1]]

print(q0, q1)
```

```
2.0 -1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I see is to use regex :

```py
q0, q1 = map(float, re.findall(r'{"pos": {"q0": (-?\d+\.\d+), "q1": (-?\d+\.\d+)}}', res)[-1])
```

Detailing the two main steps:

- First we extract each `q0` and `q1` pair from each complete JSON :

```
pattern = r'{"pos": {"q0": (-?\d+\.\d+), "q1": (-?\d+\.\d+)}}'
pairs = re.findall(pattern, res)
```

- Then we cast the last pair to float:

```py
q0, q1 = map(float, pairs[-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

this should do the trick, it’s very problem-specific though and depends on the possible data on that socket:

```py
pos_strings = [x for x in res.split('}{')[1:-1] if x[0:6] == '"pos":']
pos_object = json.loads('{%s}' % pos_strings[-1])
q0 = pos_object['pos']['q0']
q1 = pos_object['pos']['q1']
```

Answer (score 1):

- slice at find first open curly bracket
- slice at first open/close curly bracket

```
res = '''res = "atus": "OK"}{"pos": {"q0": 1.00, "q1": -0.00}}{"status": "OK"}{"pos": {"q0": 2.00, "q1": -1.00}}{"status": "OK"}{"pos": {"q0": 3.00,"'''

res = res[res.index("{"):]
json.loads(res[:res.index("}{")+1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Another regex solution - it works if **only** the *pos dictionaries* have a dictionary for a value, a double `}}` in the string.

```
import json
p = r'{[^}]+}}'
pos = re.findall(p,string_in_question)
print(json.loads(pos[-1]))
```